# OPC-UA Variable : value increasing or decreasing

Tags: python, variables, conditional-statements, logic, opc-ua

I am trying to implement following logic.

There is a saw which moves up and down for cutting a metal piece. It works on saw position - angle of saw.

The machine is called [KASTO](https://www.kastoshop.com/products/kastohbs-1-more-economy) and is similar to the machine shown in image on this website.

Following are the important values:

**condition 1:** If saw position (angle) is greater than 52 and less than 62, it is at its starting position and not yet started cutting the metal.

**condition 2:** If saw position is at 52 then it started cutting the metal (i need to log timestamp here)

**condition 3:** If the saw position is between 52 to 1, then cutting is in progress. (decreasing value from 52 to 1)

**condition 4:** If the saw reaches 0 then the cutting has been completed.
Now saw moves back to the starting position (increasing values from 0 till 62)

This is a process and I receive this saw "position" value from a sensor. We used opcua to read this value and publish.

Now the problem is: 
How do I know if the saw is moving upward or downward depending on only this "position" value variable (it is continuously updating as per saw position)?
I do know that values can be stored in a list and checked if ascending or descending.

Comment: Store the history of the value in a list and check in that list for a trend by looking at differences (changes) of the value over time. Depending on the noise of the measurement you may need to average differences between multiple values there. In the beginning of the measurement you may have to wait until you have enough data (or decide on a direction to start with if this is the control). What did you try so far or where is your problem exactly?

Comment: @Trilarion I have basic programming and  python understanding. My approach : To have function which takes these incoming values and store in a list. Once the list has enough values (5-7) it can be checked if its increasing or decreasing using sort functions. Based on that, this function will return true or false to let user know the piece has been started cutting and has been finished cutting. I have problem with figuring out the initial if conditions and storing the incoming values in a list as the values are arriving continuously.

Comment: Adding numbers to a list and removing numbers from it in Python is relatively easy - just use list operations like `insert` or `remove` for example. Not sure what is meant by initial if conditions. You basically wait until the list has a certain length and only then start removing old elements and computing the direction.

Comment: @Trilarion Thank you for your inputs. I found way to do this using **Concept of Wave**. Wave Crest: The highest part of a wave (upper limit). Wave Trough: The lowest part of a wave (lower limit). Then insert and move into Queue (Array with FIFO Order). Check with required conditions if its Crest Or Trough and above mentioned values in IF condition. It worked!

Comment: Good to hear. This also means that you could maybe answer your own question now, if you want with some example code. However, I believe the question could have been a bit clearer, maybe accompanied by some example data to show where the real problems were in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Because the sensor is generating real-time data and the data change rate is very high,
you must keep last 2 values.and with your last 2 values you can reach you questions answer.If you are working with OPC-UA-SERVER and OPC_UA_CLIENT you can write node method service and use Alarm in OPC.